# how to change <shift-K> to lookup python3 keyword instead of python2.7

Tags: manpages

I love that when working in python I can hover my cursor over a keyword a (e.g. math) and see docs in a less format to briefly read the api and then go back to writing.

I noticed in python, vim is loading python2.7 docs.  Is there a way to change the default to 3?'

running OSX Catalina vim version 8.1.1312 and use homebrew for python3.X

Answer (score 2):

Vim uses the `pydoc` command to display Python help, so if your system has a `pydoc` that defaults to Python 3, its setup will work as expected out of the box.

But I imagine that's perhaps not the case with Mac OS X and Python 3 from Homebrew. So you can consider updating your Vim setup to use a more appropriate `pydoc` that matches your system.

This setting is controlled by the [`'keywordprg'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27keywordprg%27) option.

The Python filetype support shipped with Vim doesn't allow much customization for this particular option, so the best way for you to override it is to write your own custom Python filetype plug-in, that will run *after* the one in Vim runtimes, that will override `'keywordprg'` to the setting that makes sense to your system.

Create a file named `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` and add this single line to it:

```
setlocal keywordprg=pydoc3
```

That's assuming you can use a `pydoc3` command that's in your `$PATH` to look up Python 3 docs. If that's not the right command, update to one that will work for you. You can use a full path if needed. If you need spaces, escape them with backslashes. Example:

```
setlocal keywordprg=/usr/local/bin/python3\ -m\ pydoc
```